# Suffix and Prefix Asterisk in combination with Wildcard in Datadog Metrics

Tags: dashboard, metrics, datadog

It's quite simple: I have

- a datadog-dashbaord
- a [template-variable](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/template_variables/) named `env`, which can have following values `['prod', 'test']`

[image]

And I want to display metrics based on the `env`:

- `from`-resource for `test` is `unified-importer-test-sqsimportdlq11419573-xl6dn7o5wqtj`
- `from`-resource for `prod` is `unified-importer-prod-sqsimportdlq11419573-prmohksrvxxg`

So naturally I'd use following syntax:
`unified-importer-$env.value-sqsimportdlq*`

But this does not display anything, nor shows it any error.

This, however, works as expected: `unified-importer-test-sqsimportdlq*` (or `unified-importer-prod-sqsimportdlq*` respectively).

It looks like asterisk in combination with wildcards is not working.

Additionally, DD seems to dislike using two asterisks (as prefix and suffix):
[image]

How can I leverage the template-var `env` easily in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out that following solution works:

```
sum:aws.sqs.approximate_number_of_messages_visible{service:unified-importer AND env:$env.value AND queuename IN (unified-importer-test-sqsimportdlq86419573-al6dn7o5wqtj,unified-importer-prod-sqsimportdlq86419573-prmohksrvmxg)}
```

Comment: Have the same issue regarding SQS messages and Datadog variable template. I am not sure why but this solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to use the template variable in the middle of a string, it can only go at the end. That would be a feature request to the Datadog team

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the variable in a template, but what I did is use the template in the variable, for example, instead of:

Variable having value `prod` and use it as `env:$env.value,queuename:*$env.value-sqsimportdlq*` for `queue:

I changed the variable values to contain the wildcard, like `*prod*,*test*` and use it as `env:$env.value,queuename:$env.value` which works. You could give it a different name and write your own values, but this worked for me.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. The value in the preview comes wrapped in quotations which seems to indicate that the asterisk is being treated as the character * rather than a wildcard.